# SQL Server 2008R2 - INSERT from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, select, join, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

I am having an issue (well two issues actually) with my stored procedure, and I could be making a rookie error here but I've attempted to fix it and failed miserably. Enter the gurus of stack overflow to save me :D

I want to be able to insert a new appointment into my appointment table using a stored procedure (the workings of it below). The problem is that I am trying to get the Stylist and Client ID's by the input of their names (obviously these are in separate tables and you can see where I've tried to get a hold of the ID's in the code snippet...) Anyway, I haven't got any errors as such, but it doesn't actually DO anything, as in nothing gets inserted into the appointments table when the stored procedure is tested (it executes fine). I am not sure why this is and I have no idea where to start looking.

There is one other issue which may be related, and that's the c.fullName and s.fullName are constantly underlined with a red line and it says they could not be found. BOTH of these columns exist in the client and stylist tables; they are both computed columns (firstname + lastname) and work in other queries just fine, so I don't understand why they don't work here.

```
@AppDate date = null,
@AppTime time(5) = null,
@Details varchar(255) = null,
@ClientName varchar(50) = null,
@StylistName varchar(50) = null,
@ClientID int = null,
@StylistID int = null

INSERT into appointment(appDate, appTime, details, clientID, stylistID)
SELECT
    @AppDate AS appDate, 
    @AppTime AS appTime, 
    @Details AS details,
    @ClientID, 
    @StylistID
FROM appointment a
JOIN client c 
ON c.clientID = a.clientID
JOIN stylist s
ON s.stylistID = a.stylistID
WHERE c.fullName = @ClientName
AND s.fullName = @StylistName
```

Any ideas or tips would be very much appreciated :)

EDIT:
I just noticed that when I logged out and back in again it removed the issues with the fullName columns - I did try this before but it didn't work, but obviously now it doesn't seem to be an issue... the stored procedure still doesn't insert anything though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mistake #1:

You are not even trying to insert ClientID and StylistID from tables but you are inserting back the input parameters @ClientID and @StylistID. You whole select is not selecting anything from tables.

However that's not causing the rows not to be inserted, because they would have been inserted with NULL values if they were returned by select.

Mistake #2:

Your query is actually searching for existing appointments with same Client and Stylist. I am guessing those don't exist and that's why no rows are inserted. If they did exist you would duplicate them with this insert.

Fix:

Search for ClientID and StylistID before INSERT statement. Remove @ClientID and @StylistID from input parameters and declare them in procedure body.

```
DECLARE @ClientID int;
DECLARE @StylistID int;

SELECT @ClientID = ClientID FROM client WHERE fullName = @ClientName
SELECT @StylistID = StylistID FROM stylist WHERE fullName = @StylistName


INSERT into appointment(appDate, appTime, details, clientID, stylistID)
SELECT
    @AppDate AS appDate, 
    @AppTime AS appTime, 
    @Details AS details,
    @ClientID, 
    @StylistID
```

PS: CTRL-SHIFT-R to refresh Intelli-sense when something is underlined red and it shouldn't be

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! I can see where I was going wrong now (easy when you know how hehe) thanks for putting it so clearly :)